# Позиционирование внутри <td> 2 элементов

Tags: html

Здравствуйте.
Внутри  есть картинка и текст под ней.
Можно ли сделать так чтобы картинка была по центру а текст по левому краю?

```
<td><img><br><span>text</span></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте картинке `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` :

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
      <br>
      <span>text</span>
    </td>
    
    <td>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
      <br>
      <span>text</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**p.s:** ячейке можно задать `text-align: left;`, чтобы наверняка выровнять текст по левому краю ( на случай если выше задано выравнивание по центру, например для всей таблицы).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь